# Second-order pole in Feynman diagrams

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, research-level, feynman-diagrams, many-body

[image: one of the three connected diagrams]

I am calculating density-density correlation function for a homogeneous electron gas.  The Green's function for one of three first order connected diagrams(see attached figure) is,
$$  \textit{v} _q'  {G^0{(p, i p_m )}}^2  G^0{(p+q', ip_m+i \omega _{n'})} G^0{(p+q, ip_m+i \omega _n)}$$
with sum over $p, i p_m$ and $q', i \omega _{n'} . $

I now want to perform Matsubara sum for the frequencies, $ i \omega _{n'} $ (which is easy to calculate) and $ i p_m$ (here there exist a second order pole  in the Green's function).

My question is how to take the contribution of second-order pole into account. I mean basically how to calculate the Matsubara sum for second order pole.

Comment: In fact, I solved it myself.
The final expression doesn't come out as nice as it'd have been for a simple pole. Please write to me ( comment on this question) if anybody wants the final expression. Thanks.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you want to see gshyam's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found by employing the residue theorem for higher-order poles or by simply noting that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{ik_n} \frac{1}{\left( ik_n - \xi_1 \right)^2} = \lim_{\xi_2 \rightarrow \xi_1} \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{ik_n} \frac{e^{ik_n\eta}}{\left( ik_n - \xi_1 \right) \left( ik_n - \xi_2 \right)} = \lim_{\xi_2 \rightarrow \xi_1} \frac{n_F(\xi_1) - n_F(\xi_2)}{\xi_1 - \xi_2} =  \frac{\partial n_F}{\partial \xi_1},
\end{equation}
where $\eta = 0^+$ is a convergence factor, which is not needed for higher-order poles since the integrand goes as $R^{1-n}$ on the great circle with $n\geq2$ the order of the pole.