# About Second-Order Poles of Matsubara Sum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, calculus, singularities, analyticity

I would like to ask about the calculation regarding Matsubara sum of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i\omega_n} \frac{1}{(i\omega_n-\xi)^2}
\end{equation}
which is a second order pole with residue zero (by definition, the residue is the coefficient of the term $(z-\xi)^{-1}$). Therefore I expect the Matsubara sum to be zero. However as stated in this the reply of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200903/):

> The solution can be found by employing the residue theorem for higher-order poles or by simply noting that
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{ik_n} \frac{1}{\left( ik_n - \xi_1 \right)^2} = \lim_{\xi_2 \rightarrow \xi_1} \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{ik_n} \frac{e^{ik_n\eta}}{\left( ik_n - \xi_1 \right) \left( ik_n - \xi_2 \right)} = \lim_{\xi_2 \rightarrow \xi_1} \frac{n_F(\xi_1) - n_F(\xi_2)}{\xi_1 - \xi_2} =  \frac{\partial n_F}{\partial \xi_1},
> \end{equation}

And also the same result is shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency). I would like to ask why we should do the summation in this way, and what is the justification/physical argument behind this trick.

Comment: Why you expect Matsubara sum to be zero ? For example, check summation [over all harmonics](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%28i+%5Comega+n-%5Cxi%29%5E2%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity) in WolframAlpha, and you'll see that expression converges. Similarly it may converge summing over arbitrary frequencies. Unless $i\omega_n = \xi$, which would give a discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I just found the reason after getting stuck for a couple days.
The reason I argued that the sum is zero is because I misunderstand the equation. The results should be
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i\omega_n}g(i\omega_n)=\sum_{\text{poles }\xi} \text{Res}[g(z)n_F(z)]|_{z=\xi}
\end{equation}
The residue here is the residue of product of two functions, instead of $g(i\omega_n)$, which would be the same only for first-order pole. This is where I get confused. Sorry for that.